# xml or text instead of json possible in devbridge autocomplete API?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete from devbridge. i am facing problem because of json and comma in my output data.Is it possible to use the xml or plain output text instead of json?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible looking at the source code of the plugin:

```
processResponse: function(text) {
  var response;
  try {
    response = eval('(' + text + ')');
  } catch (err) { return; }
  if (!$.isArray(response.data)) { response.data = []; }
  if(!this.options.noCache){
    this.cachedResponse[response.query] = response;
    if (response.suggestions.length === 0) { this.badQueries.push(response.query); }
  }
  if (response.query === this.getQuery(this.currentValue)) {
    this.suggestions = response.suggestions;
    this.data = response.data;
    this.suggest(); 
  }
},
```

The use of `.eval()` implies javascript expression/argument so it won't parse xml nor plain text.

What is the problem with your json ? I don't see why it would not be fixable.